# Python accessing global variables using globals()

Tags: python, global

Look into below example..

```
var1 = 10
var2 = "String"
var3 = True
dic = {}

def func1():
  ...
  ...

def main():
  varN = globals().["var1"]
  Dictionary = globals().["dic"].var2('some other string')
```

How to read this ? globals () ? how is this being used and interpreted ?

Please Help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`globals()` returns a dictionary.

```
print type(globals())  # <type 'dict'>
```

So, subscript notation is enough to access the global variables.

```
print globals()["var1"]
globals()["dic"][var2] = 'some other string'
print dic   # {'String': 'some other string'}
```

Answer (score 0):

globals is a built in python function it's always available
see:
http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#globals

Comment: Answers that contains only a link are not welcomed in SO cause if the link will break in the future - the answer will be worthless.